# Combine OPUS audio packets from multiple webrtc peer connection

Tags: go, webrtc, opus

Two clients are having a conversation using webrtc service. From that,
I have two lists of `rtp.Packet` collected from each webrtc peer.

```
var list1 []*rtp.Packet
var list2 []*rtp.Packet
```

I can save each list in separate `ogg` formated file.

```
oggFile, err := oggwriter.New("list1.ogg", 48000, 2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, t := range list1 {
    if err := oggFile.WriteRTP(t); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
if err := oggFile.Close(); err != nil {
    //
}
```

So, I will get two separate audio files for each client. Works fine.

But I want to merge these two lists as this is a conversation. Like below

```
// adding all packets in a list
list := make([]*rtp.Packet, 0)
for _, p := range list1 {
    list = append(list, p)
}
for _, p := range list2 {
    list = append(list, p)
}

// sorting packets based on timestamp
sort.Slice(list, func(i, j int) bool {
    return list[i].Timestamp < list[i].Timestamp
})
```

Now, if I save this list, I was supposed to get actual conversation between two clients.

But this doesn't work. Seems like, only one client is talking and the other one is mute.

As far as I understand, there is something in the header in each packet. When I have merged them into a single list, they got messed up. And eventually not working as expected.

> Note: users are connected to the same server. all packets are available in real-time sequentially.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The question appears to contan three very loosely coupled parts, so it's very hard to understand 1) what's going on; 2) what you're doing; 3) what problem you have with (2). To explain: the question starts with a piece of obviously incorrect code: the callback spawns a goroutine and immediately exits. The goroutine ostensibly reads a packet from some stream and does nothing with it (it does not use the `pkt` variable, so the code as shown won't even compile). Then, there is no connection between "it's fine to write data from separate streams to separate files"…

Comment: …and  and "writing to a single file" fails. Based on the code snippet I may do a very sheer guess that the culprit it lack of proper synchronization (and building your code with `go install -race` might detect that).

Comment: So you really should work on improving your question. Presently, all we could say is that "yes, probably there is some problem", but this won't move you closer to solving it.

Comment: there are lots of parts in the original code. I just shared an idea of what I am doing.

Comment: you are looking for an audio mixer, i doubt this (https://github.com/go-mix/mix) will solve your issue but that might a good starter.

Comment: If I save packets from peer1 in a file, I can play and its ok. If I save packets from peer2 in different file, that's works too. problem is how to save packets from two peer in a single file.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you can see what consitutes an answearble question; yours is unfortunately does not meed these criteria. I _do_ understand it may be very hard to ask a proper question with an MCVE in some cases, but then it's unfit for StackOverflow; please consider asking it on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) or [r/golang](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/)—to take two suitable venues.

Comment: «problem is how to save packets from two peer in a single file»—and that's precisely what I'm talking about: there's no code which does this which we could study and point to a flaw (if any), so the only answer is "take the samples from both sources and _properly_ write them to a file". This won't help you much, as already stated.

Comment: the question might deserve little refactoring to focus on how to mixin multiple audio input to a single output. with a demo code of what you are able to do so far, but only containing audio related code, skip the webrtc part.

Comment: I will update this question. thanks

Comment: tried my best to explain more clearly. tnx @kostix

Comment: The question now looks very good to me; notice how it allowed for an answer by Philipp Hancke which seems to be the spot on ;-)

Comment: @MirShahriarSabuj If possible I would start with doing PCM maybe? WebRTC supports alaw/ulaw and that will take out the step of encoding/decoding Opus.

Answer (score 1):

The RTP packets contain a header with a timestamp attribute. Note that this isn't an absolute timestamp and it starts at a random offset which breaks your sorting idea.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550 for the full details. The packets will typically also include a synchronization source or ssrc which identifies a series of packets belonging to the same sender.

You will need to extract the payload from the packet, then use a decoder (typically the opus decoder) to decode them. Then you will have two different pcm/wav files and can then combine these e.g. using ffmpeg. But make sure you get the time offset between both streams right

Answer (score 0):

This is more a generic answer, might give you pointer to look at,
What you need is a mixer to received all audio data from the peers and write it into array be it ogg or pcm and handle it whichever way you want.
Please look into the webrtc api list if there is any support for audio mixer and try use that.